# Grub not booting unless I click esc to open console mode

Tags: boot, grub2

My system has weird issue: when I try to boot normally I just get black screen, but if I click escape when booting to open grub console then it's fine (and I have to switch from grub console to normal mode by typing "normal", clicking enter and then escape again)

Any ideas :)?

Thanks

Comment: Providing OS & release details maybe a start.  We currently have no idea about what type of system you're asking about.

Comment: Maybe your grub configuration is in wrong way. Paste your grub default config via
`cat /etc/default/grub` to check GRUB_TIMEOUT, GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE
[GRUB Simple configuration handling](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration)